# Populate drop-down using Json data that is from database(using Python FLASK)

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have JSON data which I retrieved from a PostgreSQL database into Flask function that returns the following:

Flask function:

```
def Install():
    cur = conn.cursor()
    # cur.execute("""create table Install (Install varchar(300));""")
    # cur.execute("""insert into Install (Install) values ('ffr2nightly.tst');""")
    cur.execute("""select * from Install;""")
    conn.commit()
    test = {}
    count = 0
    for row in cur.fetchall():
        test[count] = row[0]
        count += 1
    return test
```

Output:

```
{  
   "0": "ffr2nightly.tst",
   "1": "ffr2nightly.tst",
   "2": "HealthCheckDocker.tst",
   "3": "NoInstall.tst"
}
```

I am trying to use this data in my HTML form with dropdown list

HTML:

```
<select multiple="multiple" id='lstBox3' class="col-md-5">
  <option>
    // I want the Json data in these options
  </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you just need to extract the values from the JSON, then parse it into the select element using jQuery.

```js
//Your data
var data = {
  "0": "ffr2nightly.tst",
  "1": "ffr2nightly.tst",
  "2": "HealthCheckDocker.tst",
  "3": "NoInstall.tst"
};
//iterate through it and append to the select
Object.values(data).forEach(function(ele) {
  var opt = '<option>' + ele + '</option>';
  $('#sel').append(opt);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="sel"></select>
```

If you want to exclude duplicates, you just check if the option exists before adding it with this

```
if ($('#sel').find('option[value="' + ele + '"]').length == 0)
    $('#sel').append(opt);
```

Comment: I have data in a function called Install1() and assigned to a variable called test.

How can I call this function or variable in the place of
var data = {
  "0": "ffr2nightly.tst",
  "1": "ffr2nightly.tst",
  "2": "HealthCheckDocker.tst",
  "3": "NoInstall.tst"
};

Comment: Couple ways: Make it a global variable, or make my solution a function call that you can pass the variable into.

Comment: One quick update Install1() is python function on server side and test is a variable in the python function on server side.
Now can you explain me how can I get it as data in my script you have given frontend?

Comment: I don't know anything about Flask or Python. If your goal is to learn how to pass data from Python or Flask, that belongs in a separate question. This question was worded and tagged such that you had access to that json data in the front-end already.

Comment: Looking in your question history, it appears as though someone already told you how to do this yesterday. Perhaps you should look at the solution provided in your other question.

Comment: No, his answer was not relevant in the yesterdays question
Anyways Thanx for this help I will figure out how to call data.